# Nothing gets printed

Tags: java

I am new to programming. When I try to execute my program, nothing gets printed in console. But I am not getting any error while compiling. Please help.

I am trying to read the content of the file and print Yes/No based on the values 1/0 present in the file.

Here is the content of my file:

```
10000111100101010010010000100010001100010001000010000100000111111010110101011
```

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i = 1;
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\File.txt")).readLine());
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                while (i < sb.length()) {
                    if (sb.charAt(i) == 1)
                        System.out.println("Yes");
                    else if (sb.charAt(i) == 0)
                        System.out.println("No");
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } finally { 
            System.out.println("Completed.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing gets printed? Not even the "Completed."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`charAt()` returns a character. Change your `if statement` as shown below:

```
if (sb.charAt(i) == '1') {
    ...
} else if (sb.charAt(i) == '0') {
    ...
}
```

Another observation, in your code, the index variable, i, is initialized to 1. But the index of the String starts from 0. So initialize i to 0, to get the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

`charAt()` return `char` not `int`. If you assign `char` to `int` that will be converted to `ASCII` value. So your `sb.charAt(i)==1` will be false even for `1`.  Write like:

```
if (sb.charAt(i) == '1')
     System.out.println("Yes");
else if (sb.charAt(i) == '0')
    System.out.println("No");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods for you to get the expected result.

**Method one**

Change

```
 if (sb.charAt(i) == 1)
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                else if (sb.charAt(i) == 0)
                    System.out.println("No");
```

to

```
if (sb.charAt(i) == '1')
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                else if (sb.charAt(i) == '0')
                    System.out.println("No");
                i++;
```

**Method Two**

You can compare the char value using Ascii.

In Ascii, char '1' is 49; char '0' is 48. Use the following code, you can get the expected result as well.

```
  if (sb.charAt(i) == 49)
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                else if (sb.charAt(i) == 48)
                    System.out.println("No");
                i++;
```